# R tapply Time Difference -- Units inconsistent

Tags: r, tapply

I've searched and failed to find this problem on SO, apologies if I've overlooked a post. 
Reproducible code so you can at least see what I'm working with, but the error doesn't reproduce (happens intermittently in my data):

```
require(dplyr)
df <-data.frame(id=as.numeric(c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3")), 
            start= c("1/31/17 10:00","1/31/17 10:02","1/31/17 10:45", 
                             "2/10/17 12:00", "2/10/17 12:20","2/11/17 09:40","2/11/17 10:00"),
            selfreport = c(12,20,10,0,10,37.5,NA))
df$time1 <- as.POSIXct(df$start,format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
df$DIFF <- unlist(tapply(df$time1,df$id, function(x) c(NA,diff(x))))

which[(df$selfreport<df$DIFF) na.action= na.pass)]
```

Problem1: The output DIFF column above is in minutes (which is what I want) but in my data, the values change to hours for only some groups. Why is this happening?

Problem2: I need to see which rows have selfreport values that are smaller than DIFF values, but leaving NA values alone. I cannot figure out where to put the `na.action` without an error message.

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Dear Bananas; It's better to cite what you found during your searches than it is to request forgiveness. Also better is to _not_ finish with a coda expressing conditional appreciation. It's considered "noise" by the site developers. We all slavishly adhere to their all-knowing guidance in this regard.

Comment: On the substance rather than the form of your question: The print representation of datetimes at midnight often "looks like" just Dates. I cannot tell whether this applies to your problem since your example does actually "exemplify" the issue.

Comment: @42-, Duly noted. Anything else I can provide that would help communicate my question(s)? I know my example doesn't exemplify the issue...

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the problem you can say `df %>% filter(!is.na(DIFF)) %>% filter(selfreport < DIFF)`.